# How to generate confusion matrix using test results?

Tags: yolo, confusion-matrix, yolov4

I obtained test results(bbox size, location) via code below,

!./darknet detector map data/data.obj cfg/yolov4-obj.cfg backup/yolov4_last.weights -ext_output <data/test.txt> result.txt

and want to generate confusion matrix with it.

How can i make one?